# C# ¿Como pasar una lista de una clase a un formulario?

Tags: c#

Cree una lista en la clase **Estudiante matriculado**, esta lista la necesito en el form **FormConsultarAlumnos** para mostrarlo en el DataGridView y hacer un filtro. Sin embargo tengo problemas para pasar esta lista al Form.

**Clase EstudianteMatriculado**

```
namespace SeleccionaUsuario
{
    class EstudianteMatriculado
    {

        private string nombreAlumno;
        private string apellidoAlumno;
        private double codigo;
        private double grupo;
        private double calificacion;

        public List<EstudianteMatriculado> listaEstudiante;

        public EstudianteMatriculado()
        {
            listaEstudiante = new List<EstudianteMatriculado>();
        }



        public EstudianteMatriculado(string nombreAlumno, string apellidoAlumno, double codigo, double grupo, double calificacion)
        {
            this.NombreAlumno = nombreAlumno;
            this.apellidoAlumno = apellidoAlumno;
            this.Codigo = codigo;
            this.Grupo = grupo;
            this.Calificacion = calificacion;
        }


        public void matricularEstudiante()
        {
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno1 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Alejandra", "Bejarano Montero", 1759869, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno2 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Giancarlo", "Mendoza Muñoz", 1759620, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno3 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Camilo", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759589, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno4 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Mia", "Thermopolis", 1759756, 50, 0);
            EstudianteMatriculado alumno5 = new EstudianteMatriculado("Laura", "Perez Rodriguez", 1759770, 50, 0);

            listaEstudiante.Add(alumno1);
            listaEstudiante.Add(alumno2);
            listaEstudiante.Add(alumno3);
            listaEstudiante.Add(alumno4);
            listaEstudiante.Add(alumno5);
        }

        FormAgregarCalificacion form = new FormAgregarCalificacion(listaEstudiante);





        public string NombreAlumno { get => nombreAlumno; set => nombreAlumno = value; }
        public string ApellidoAlumno { get => apellidoAlumno; set => apellidoAlumno = value; }
        public double Codigo { get => codigo; set => codigo = value; }
        public double Grupo { get => grupo; set => grupo = value; }
        public double Calificacion { get => calificacion; set => calificacion = value; }



    }
}
```

**Clase FormConsultarAlumno**

```
namespace SeleccionaUsuario{
    public partial class FormConsultarAlumnos : Form
    {


        EstudianteMatriculado listaEstudiante;

        DataTable directorio = new DataTable();



        public FormConsultarAlumnos(EstudianteMatriculado listaEstudiante)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listaEstudiante = listaEstudiante;




            directorio.Columns.Add("Nombre estudiante");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Apellido");
            directorio.Columns.Add("codigo");
            directorio.Columns.Add("Grupo");


            /*
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno1.NombreAlumno, alumno1.ApellidoAlumno, alumno1.Codigo, alumno1.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno2.NombreAlumno, alumno2.ApellidoAlumno, alumno2.Codigo, alumno2.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno3.NombreAlumno, alumno3.ApellidoAlumno, alumno3.Codigo, alumno3.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno4.NombreAlumno, alumno4.ApellidoAlumno, alumno4.Codigo, alumno4.Grupo);
            directorio.Rows.Add(alumno5.NombreAlumno, alumno5.ApellidoAlumno, alumno5.Codigo, alumno5.Grupo);
            */
            dgvEstudiantes.DataSource = directorio;

            FormAgregarCalificacion form = new FormAgregarCalificacion(directorio);



        }
```

En el constructor del **FormConsultarAlumnos** aparece el siguiente error:
Incoherencia de accesibilidad: el tipo de parámetro 'EstudianteMatriculado' es menos accesible que el método 'FormConsultarAlumnos...'

No se en que pueda estar fallando he leído la documentación y esto se puede hacer de diversas maneras, sin embargo decidí realizarlo de esta forma.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando haces esto:

```
class EstudianteMatriculado {...}
```

Y no aclaras la visibilidad, la misma es por defecto privada, que es lo que te esta diciendo el error.

Aunque no es la mejor forma de escribirlo, lo que te dice es que EstudianteMatriculado  es **menos visible** que **FormConsultarAlumnos** (en este caso tu constructor)

```
public class EstudianteMatriculado {...}
```

Agregale a tu clase un public adelante y todo se solucionara.

Comment: ♦    C# Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Riaven aparece un error al implementar tu corrección la lista es de tipo **MaticularEstudiante** no de el form el cual esta. Por lo tanto aparece "No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo System..."

Comment: Eso es para una pregunta nueva o pedir ayuda a la persona que ha respondido, editando la respuesta no es la manera.